Welder not passing current from a short pulse
I am trying to use a 5V control signal to operate a solid state relay (datasheet below)
https://assets.rs-online.com/v1698808049/Datasheets/e3347be1ffb933a5483cd852b7d90659.pdf
Once open, I would like my trigger circuit to cause a spark which allows the current from welder to pass.
This was working when using a custom (and now broken) board, but when we replaced the current source with a cheap welder we no longer are able to get the current to fire from welder.
The welder and board are same current and the same voltage, and when I use the welder with a physical tap in the same configuration it works.
https://www.amazon.com/HONE-Inverter-Machines-Anti-Stick-Efficiency/dp/B092W224S8
My guess is that the welder is taking too long to output the current so it’s “missing” the pulse.  I can’t find any diagrams of welder output current vs time but effectively I have about 150us for the welder to start to pass current and maintain the arc.
If anyone has any thoughts I’d love to hear them, and also if anyone has any info about output current vs time on a cheap welder I would love to know more.

I love SMAW, MIG, and TIG welding as a farm hand. I enjoy the work very much. It is part of who I am as a person. But I don't understand your situation well enough to be of help.  Can you add more detail? I'd like to help. But it's not clear to me yet how I might be of any use. My heart is with you, though.

Thanks for the response! I guess in a nutshell I’m wondering if anyone knows (even to just the order of magnitude what the slew rate is on a typical welder (A/s on output rise time)

Are you looking to tack weld? I can't tell from your writing. May just be my ignorance. I just do farm projects after all. I'm not a professional.

If it is a ‘stick’ AKA arc welder and it is a modern inverter design, most if not all impose a frequency, high voltage on the output for ‘scratch start’. The SSR will probably not appreciate this nor would a standard electromagnetic relay as there is a few 1000 V involved. You would need to intercept the welder circuitry to selectively enable/disable it. For a TIG or MIG welder it is much easier as you simply connect a relay to the trigger switch. You might be able to find schematics for your welder online - for many of the Chinese sourced ones they tend to be variations on a standard design.
